# How to change shape area units in V-LATE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, units

So I am working with land use shapefile. During the creation of polygons automatically created shape_area column with values that was not good for me so I created new column and with calculate geometry recalculated area of polygons in units that are correct for me. Now for the landscape metrics I use extension V-LATE, Vector-based Landscape Analysis Tools 2.0. During the calculation it automatically uses original shape_area column which one I cannot delete or change.

How can I make V-LATE use a column that I created?

Comment: Shapefiles don't usually *have* a `shape_area` column. Some applications (including Esri ArcGIS tools, of which V-LATE is a mature extension) provide a *virtual* column of the computed Cartesian area, called "shape_area", but it's not an actual part of the dBase table. The only way to get the *virtual* area to be in the right units is to reproject the shapefile. An enhancement request to the maintainer is is your best hope to permit use of a custom column.